# Carbon - "The date does not match the format d/m/Y H:i:s."

Tags: laravel

'm trying to store a date value but is always appearing the validation error:

```
"The date does not match the format d/m/Y H:i:s."
```

Do you know where can be the issue? Validate method:

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'date1' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y H:i:s',
      'date2' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y H:i:s|after_or_equal:date1',
 ]);
```

**To create Im using carbon to format the dates:**

```
 Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $request->date1)
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $request->date2)
```

**The Js code is:**

```
$( ".input-group.date").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        minuteStep: 5
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing the date string in `dd MM yyyy - hh:ii` format, change validation rules date format too:

```
'date1' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i',
'date2' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i|after_or_equal:date1',
```

And then use the same format to create Carbon instance:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->date1)
Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->date2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get "The date does not match the format d m Y - H:i."

Comment: @JohnZ please show what string exactly do you get from datepicker.

Comment: what do you get when you `dd($request->date1)` whatever format is actually being received by the back end should be the format you use.

Comment: @johnZ change as it's showing February it's using `F` not `m`. `F` being: A full textual representation of a month

Comment: @JohnZ as Option said you need to use `F` instead of `m` in this case. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks, do you know why is appearing "InvalidArgumentException
Unexpected data found."?

Comment: @JohnZ no, but if you'll not be able to find out, please ask a new question and attach full error message and related code.